# Aspect Fill on navigation bar image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I'm wanting to achieve the same look as an imageView's aspect fill for my navigation controller's background image.

Currently I'm using this to setup the image:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(imageToCache?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: UIImageResizingMode.stretch), for: .default)
```

UIImageResizingMode.stretch obviously gives me a nasty stretched look. I don't care if the image is getting cut off on the top/bottom, I'm just needing it to be put into the nav bar full sized and what shows shows.

I can't just pass in nil to the resizing mode.

There's also the

```
init(rawValue:))
```

option for the resizing mode, but any number I put in there results in there being no image in the background anymore.

Any ideas?

edit:

```
let picture = passedPerson.pictureURL!


         if let imageFromCache = MainPageVC.imageCache.object(forKey: picture as String as NSString) {


                var titleView = UIImageView()
                titleView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
              titleView.image = imageFromCache

        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView  } else {
        print(picture)
        var requested = URLRequest(url: URL(string: picture)!)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requested) {data, response, err in


            if err != nil {

                print(err?.localizedDescription)
            } else {


                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)

                    MainPageVC.imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: picture as String as NSString)

                    var titleView = UIImageView()
                    titleView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    titleView.image = imageToCache

                    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView


                  //  UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(imageToCache?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: UIImageResizingMode.stretch), for: .default)
                }

            }

            }.resume()
```

The above results in no picture showing up.

Comment: set contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

Comment: @NazmulHasan I added an edit if you could look at it. Any ideas why that's making no picture show up?

Comment: @NazmulHasan Yeah I'm running an if/else on it to download if not. The code worked with downloading/caching when I was using the UINavigationBar.appearance() code, but trying to use a view instead is not working.

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(imageToCache, forBarMetrics: .Default)

Comment: Yep that was it. Thank you so much. I don't know why I was using the resizable one lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this . hope it you will work

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(imageToCache‌​, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```